# Console keeps giving me NAN

Tags: c#, nan

I'm writing a simple a loan repayment calculator. When I run this code the console outputs 'Nan' no matter what numbers I use. I'm not sure if my math is wrong or if I'm misusing the "Math." function.

```
int choice=1;

Console.WriteLine("1. Find out how many months it will take to pay off the loan: ");
Console.WriteLine("2. Can I afford it? ");
Console.WriteLine("3. Exit ");

choice = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

if (choice == 1){

    Console.WriteLine("Enter amount borrowed: ");
    double borrowed = double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the interest rate: ");
    double rate = double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Enter monthly payment: ");
    double monthly = double.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        
    double answer = Math.Ceiling((Math.Log10(monthly)-Math.Log10(monthly-borrowed*rate))/(Math.Log10(1+rate/12)));

    Console.WriteLine(answer);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: The console doesn't "give" a NaN. It simply prints out the value supplied to it. Go back and find out where the NaN was introduced; then ask a *specific* question about that, should it remain. I would recommend breaking down the long expression before; it will help isolation of the issue of where the NaN(s) were first introduced. Keep in mind that NaNs are contagious and will contaminate all further math.

Comment: Can you be more specific.

Comment: This looks nothing like an `amortization` app use the debugger and step thru the code

Comment: Only the Mafia charges borrowed*rate interest every month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 based logarithm can not be calculated from a negative number. I suggest this function call will void your answer as Not a Number (NaN).

```
Math.Log10(monthly-borrowed*rate)
```

Then again, it's all about the input. As the commentors suggest, use a debugger to step through your application.

Answer (score 2):

You get Nan because of  `Math.Log10(monthly - borrowed * rate))`

the interval of definition of Log10 is ]0,+∞ [.

`if(monthly - borrowed * rate) < 0` the log10 function is not defined.

Your alogorthm is not good.

let say that borrowed  =B, rate = r, monthly = m and months number = x.

if the r is the anual rate and it was in percent :

```
        Log(m) - Log(m - Br/12)
x = ---------------------------------   r is the percent (ex 0.01) 
                  Log(1 + r/12)
```

I suppose that you get (m - Br/12) < 0 because you forget to devide r by 100

Answer (score 2):

If you *refactor* your complicated expression into its component pieces:

```
double borrowed = 20000.00      ;
double rate     = 6.00 / 100.00 ; // 6% interest
double monthly  = 500.00        ;

double monthlyLog10          = Math.Log10( monthly ) ;
double monthlyPrincipal      = monthly - borrowed * rate ;
double monthlyPrincipalLog10 = Math.Log10( monthlyPrincipal ) ;
double mpr                   = 1.0 + rate / 12.0 ;
double mprLog10              = Math.Log10( mpr     ) ;
double delta                 = monthlyLog10 - monthlyPrincipalLog10 ;
double result                = delta / mprLog10 ;
double answer                = Math.Ceiling( result ) ;
```

You'll discover that in this case, `monthly - borrowed * rate` works out to be `-700.0`. Then you'll discover that log<sub>10</sub>( -700.00 ) is ... NaN.

Hence your problem.

If you use the [correct formula](http://oakroadsystems.com/math/loan.htm), you'll see that your code is simpler:

```
double amountBorrowed        = 20000.00            ; // A: the loan principal
double monthlyInterestRate   = (6.0/100.00) / 12.0 ; // i: periodic interest rate (here, 6% per year / 12 to get the monthly interest rate)
double monthlyPayment        = 250.00              ; // P: periodic payment
double totalNumberOfPayments = -Math.Log( 1 - ((monthlyInterestRate*amountBorrowed) / monthlyPayment) )
                             /  Math.Log( 1+monthlyInterestRate ) ;
```